# How do I get javadoc to link to the Java API using an Ant task?

Tags: ant, javadoc

Right now my ant task looks like.

```
<javadoc sourcepath="${source}" destdir="${doc}">
    <link href="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/" />
</javadoc>
```

And I'm getting this warning:

```
javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/package-list
```

How do I get the javadoc to properly link to the API?  I am behind a proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need the [http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort system properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html) set. For example, `ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.y.com" ant doc`

Alternatively, you could set the "offline" flag and provide a package list, but that could be a pain for the Java core.

Answer (score 12):

You can also pass the arguments inside the ant task

```
<arg value="-J-Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.here"/>
<arg value="-J-Dhttp.proxyPort=##"/>
```

If going the offline link route.  Download the package list by going to the URL of the Java API (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/package-list) and saving it as a text file and then using this Ant task.

```
<javadoc sourcepath="${source}" destdir="${doc}">
    <link offline="true" href="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/" packagelistloc="path-containing-package-list"/>
</javadoc>
```

Comment: Note that `path-containing-package-list` above means the path of a directory that contains a file called `package-list`. It's not the path of the `package-list` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "offline" mode that allows you to build (faster!) without accessing the internet. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089805/366749